# Node.js 'Not Found' callback for async.detect?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback, detect

I have a file path list `file_paths`, and I want to detect which file exists.
If any file exists, I want to read that one. Otherwise call another function, 
`not_found` for example.

I wish to use [`async.detect`](https://github.com/caolan/async#detect) but I found no way to add a 'Not Found' callback 
when all the iterators return `false`.

I've tried this one, but no work. Returned undefined and nothing outputted.

```
async = require 'async'

async.detect [1,2,3], (item, callback) ->
  callback true if item == 4
, (result) ->
  console.log result ? result : 'Not Found'
```

If there's another way to do it, please add it to the answer.

Comment: pls include code block of what you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from [the documentation](https://github.com/caolan/async#detect) you mentioned.

**in case of `detect(arr, iterator, callback)`**

> callback(result) - A callback which is called as soon as any iterator
>   returns true, or after all the iterator functions have finished.
>   **Result will be the first item in the array that passes the truth test (iterator) or the value undefined if none passed.**

from your question you want to find a way to detect if no file in list is found, which could be done by comparing the `result` with `undefined` and checking whether this condition is true.

like

```
async.detect(['file1','file2','file3'], fs.exists, function(result){

     if(typeof(result)=="undefined") {
         //none of the files where found so undefined
     }

});
```

Comment: @Rix: and what was the o/p? what did you get when you `console.log(result)`? wouldn't that be nice to mention in you question to provide some clarity?

Comment: I'm using async 0.2.9. `async.detect [1,2,3],((i,c)->c(true) if i==4),(r)->console.log r ? r : 'No'` undefined is returned, and nothing ouputed

Comment: OK. I found my fault in the code. the callback didn't called with false.

Answer (score 0):

I would use async.each and use fs.exists to detect if the file exists. If it exists, then read the file otherwise, call the not found function then proceed to the next item. See sample code I have written on top of my head below.

```
async.each(file_paths, processItem, function(err) {
  if(err) {
    console.log(err);
    throw err;
    return;
  }

  console.log('done reading file paths..');

});

function notFound(file_path) {
  console.log(file_path + ' not found..');
}

function processItem(file_path, next) {
  fs.exists(file_path, function(exists) {
    if(exists) {
      //file exists
      //do some processing
      //call next when done
      fs.readFile(file_path, function (err, data) {
        if (err) throw err;

        //do what you want here

        //then call next
        next();
      });

    }
    else {
      //file does not exist
      notFound(file_path);
      //proceed to next item
      next();
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: It's not I want. I want the `not_found` function being called just once, after all the iterators return `false`.