# Node.js async.detect if no results

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I have an array of IPs that I test against a certain condition, stopping at the first one that returns true. However, I have no way of finding whether all IPs have failed the test, as `async.detect` returns only a result when there is a success.

My code is something like this:

```
async.detect(ips, function(ip, callback) {
    if(aCertainCondition(ip)) {
      callback(null, true);
    }
}, function(err, result) {
    // my result
});
```

The documentation makes no mention of this use case, and the answer found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18426378/node-js-not-found-callback-for-async-detect) is inefficient, as it seems the `detect` method never reaches the `callback` block.

It is imperative for my use-case that the first test to succeed be returned as fast as possible, otherwise to return something to let me know that all tests failed. Is it possible using `async.detect`? Or should I use some other method/library?

Thank you.

Comment: if any one of the tests succeeds, I need that one, otherwise if all tests fail, I need to be notified somehow. Because otherwise the method just hangs indefinitely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to **always** invoke the callback, not just when the condition succeeds/fails:

```
    async.detect(ips, function(ip, callback) {

       callback(null, aCertainCondition(ip));
    }, 
    function(err, result) {
        // my result
    });
```

Comment: This indeed seems to be the answer. Thank you.